# What is the ideal ratio of Google Search Console Click / impressions

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

One of my site has following details in Google Search Console.

- Total Clicks : 2900
- Total Impression : 280,000
- So ratio is around 1.03%.

Is there any ideal ratio of  Google Search Console Click / impressions.

I asked it here if 1.03 ratio is really below to average ratio I can spend an few hours/ days to optimize titles.

Comment: Optimize both titles and descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better if you look at it on a per query (search term) level. If you think some of the queries aren't getting any clicks and has a lot of impression, you may tweak the titles and description (perhaps add call to actions) to get more clicks.

If for example the above figures are for a specific search term, I think it's quite low.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on a quite a few aspects to name a few :

- 1. Your current position for a single search term.
- 2. Type of search term for example long tail, branded, results with ads,
     results with local placement, search intent etc.
- 3. Niche your in, Niche/industry averages are significantly different, especially when narrowing down to tight niches.

Looking at Search Console and getting an average across all searches doesnt really give you much info to make goal setting judgements.

Analyse your analytics, identify key areas to improve. Use Search console as a cross check against individual page performance.  Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It can vary widely between different industries. What is a high conversion rate in one vertical can be extremely low in another and vice versa. As have been mentioned below, it also depends greatly on the type of search. For branded search you would normally expect to have a much higher rate than for more generic search terms.

Another factor to consider is how compelling the results surrounding yours are. A site could be ranking below yours but have a stronger call to action and be performing better. You should think of your page title and META description in the same way that you would the copy for an Adwords ad.

Here is a useful article from Search Engine Land on the topic of optimising your click through rate for various different verticals

https://searchengineland.com/write-meta-description-gets-clickthroughs-207922

I would also considering checking out the book Cashvertising which has hundreds of quick and easily digestible tips on writing strong copy.

Another major consideration in recent SERPs is the presence of answer boxes which can greatly improve your visibility and potentially clickthrough rate. You can find a guide to how to get into Answer boxes in the SERPS here

https://moz.com/blog/how-to-appear-in-googles-answer-boxes-whiteboard-friday

Also if you are not using schema for elements of your content such as reviews you should consider this. The star ratings that you see in the results if you do searches such as seo companies uk are generated by use of schema and can have a significant impact.